# 404 not FOUND when there is a dot(.) in the url (lighttpd)

Tags: .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I have a CodeIgniter app and have an .htaccess file with this code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|file|test.php|lib|resources|xmlhttp|dashboard.html)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

All urls are working fine except for this url

```
http://myweb.com/login?site=http://google.com
```

When I type that url in the address bar of a browser and press enter, I will get 404 NOT FOUND from lighttpd, and not from CodeIgniter (custom 404 error page) 
The cause of the 404 NOT Found is the dot(.) from google.com bcause when i remove it, it is working as what i want

But when I use the url

```
http://myweb.com/index.php/login?site=http://google.com
```

It workds as i expected

My question is, is this because of the htaccess file? or apache configuration? or something else?

Any help or ideas will be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: In your `RewriteCond`, why do you escape the first dot but not the two following ones?

Comment: It's ok, even if i escape that, it will not solve the issue. Thanks for repyling :)

Comment: Can you try and replace `^(.*)$` with `^/(.*)` (no need for the $ since .* swallows everything)?

Comment: by the way, i use lighttpd not apache.. whenever there is a dot in my url, it will display 404 NOT FOUND.. sorry for the wrong info

Comment: You should specify that in the question

Comment: i have modified my question.. i guess this has to do with lighttpd because when i run it in apache, it is ok..

Comment: I've the same problem in '16. But not with CodeIgniter, just plain PHP.